# Android: how to verify package is genuine

Tags: android, google-play, package-name

In one of my apps, I would like to detect if the user has got another app of mine installed.

This code works:

```
    PackageManager pm = mAppContext.getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo("com.example.packagename", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        // do something
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        // nothing to do
    }
```

But I wonder how I can verify that the user has genuinely downloaded the app from Google Play. I guess it would be possible to install a non genuine package with the same package name, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PackageManager** has a method **[getInstallerPackageName](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstallerPackageName%28java.lang.String%29)** that for given package name gives you name of the installer. For pre-loaded(unless they are not installed from other 'market' like SamsungApps) and self-installed applications will return null. For applications originating from Google Play you should get **com.android.vending**. And I don't think that you are able to install two applications with the same package names declared in the manifest.

Comment: what about if the genuine app has never been installed, and the non-genuine app is faking the installer information?

Comment: What do you mean by 'faking installer information'? The value returned by getInstallerPackageName is being handled by PackageManager, so I suppose, there is no way to hack this.

Comment: I guess it would be possible to maliciously hardcode whichever string in that? or maybe not?

Comment: The is no way to specify the installer name from the manifest. The installer package name is being set during the installation by the package manager.

Comment: OK, I see, it sounds promising. I am targetting Android devices 4.0 and higher. Can I assume that all genuine apps dowloaded by Android 4.0 devices report the string "com.android.vending" in it?

Comment: And what about on rooted devices. Are we sure the getInstallerPackageName return value cannot be altered there?

Comment: Either previous 'Android Market' or 'Google Play' have the 'com.android.vending' package name. But I don't know what Google is planning for the future. Considering the rooted device, I think that you should assume that someone might change this. You should describe your problem from the other perspective, maybe there's other solution.